# check if radio button is checked in ejs

Tags: javascript, if-statement, ejs

As the title says,I'm trying to check if radio button is checked,but since document isn't available,how am I supposed to do it? I want to achieve

```
<%if(radio1.checked){%>
 <%-include('./someHtml')%>
<%}%>
```

Comment: An ejs template is processed on the server, then the result is sent to the browser. ejs code is all about composing the initial document. Handling client-side clicks happens in a completely different realm.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you care only about **the state at the time the document loads**:

There's no document, but there's no radio button either.

What you have is some *data* and an EJS program.

The EJS program must already have some logic to examine that data and determine if it should output a `checked` attribute (or not) for each radio button.

Use that same logic to determine if the `include` should be used.

---

If, on the other hand, you want to **change what is displayed, live, as the user clicks on radio buttons** then you can't do that in EJS.

By the time the HTML is delivered to the browser, turned into a DOM, and rendered where the user can click on it: the EJS has **finished**.

You can either:

- Use client-side JS to change what content is shown **or**
- Replace the radio buttons with links or submit buttons and load a whole new page from the server based on the submitted data

---

Related reading:

- [What is the difference between client-side and server-side programming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840429/what-is-the-difference-between-client-side-and-server-side-programming)

Answer (score 0):

You can either send an Ajax request when clicking the radio button and handle it's state in the backend or show/hide 'someHtml' using Javascript:

```
<input
  type="radio"
  name="toggleHtml"
  onclick="document.getElementById('someHtml').style.display = 'block';" checked
/> Show

<input
  type="radio"
  name="toggleHtml"
  onclick="document.getElementById('someHtml').style.display = 'none';"   
/> Hide

<div id="someHtml">Some HTML ...</div>
```